# Link with Embedded Icon Not Working in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a menu in a Lightning component with menu items as links (`<a>`). Embedded in the `<a>` is an icon next to the link text. When clicking on the link, if the cursor clicks on the icon in the link, the link doesn't fire. If I click anywhere else inside the link, it does.

Here is my code.

```
<a data-menu-item-id="{!v.navItem.id}" onclick="{!c.onTopMenuClick}">

    <img src="{!$Resource.FutureStatePortalV1 + '/images/SVG/Home.svg'}" width="20" height="20" alt="" />

    {!v.navItem.label}

    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevrondown" alternativeText="" />
</a>
```

If I create a link with an embedded icon in plain HTML, the link fires no matter where I click on it. I don't know why this would be an issue in a Lightning component. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard components for menu [<lightning:buttonMenu>](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonMenu/example) with `<lightning:menuItem>`? or the standard css slds [Global Navigation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-navigation/)?